# routing in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony4

I want to routing for my *app* and *api* like this:

```
app:
    resource: ../src/Controller
    type: annotation
    prefix: /

api:
    resource: ../src/Controller/Api
    type: annotation
    prefix: /api
```

**Q1**: Where should I write this? in `config/routes/annotations.yaml` or 
`config/routes.yaml`.

**Q2**: what is different between this two file and which one is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `config/routes/annotations.yaml` was probably created by a flex when applying annotations recipe. I am not 100% sure, but when you want to delete the annotations bundle it will also remove this file.

But it makes sense to me to put all annotation route imports into `config/routes/annotations.yaml` file, because they just depend on this package.

Other routes you should put into the `config/routes.yaml` file.